# 複数のカスタム投稿タイプへ繋がるページャーを出力

Tags: php, wordpress

初めて利用させていただきます、宜しくお願い致します。

Wordpressのテーマにてカスタム投稿タイプを使用していますが、
複数のカスタム投稿タイプへ繋がるページャーは設定できるのでしょうか。

例えば「A」と「B」の2つのカスタム投稿タイプがあったとして、
Aの投稿ページ（仮に single-a.php とします）にページャーを設置したとき、AとBを合体させて、

```
Aの1月の投稿

↓「＜前の記事」をクリック

Bの2月の投稿

↓「＜前の記事」をクリック

Aの3月の投稿
```

のようにページを遷移させたいです。

WPはほぼ素人なので、ググってもなかなかヒットせず…。
どのような仕組みでできるか教えていただけると幸いです。
出来るか出来ないか、簡単か難しいかだけでも構いません。

宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: それはページャーと呼べないのではないのですかね？ページャーとは同じ条件で抽出されたデータの一部を等間隔に切り出してページ単位で表示する機能かと。

Comment: @keitaro_so さん　回答ありがとうございます。訳ありで、カスタム投稿タイプを「ニュース1」「ニュース2」というように、内容は連動したものだけど投稿タイプが異なる…という構成になっています。なにか条件をあわせたり、複数条件を設定できればと思ったのですが…根本的に難しいのでしょうか。

Comment: ページャーという言葉は使わないほうが良いかと思います。見た目はページャーですけど、中身が単純に特定の条件で繰り返されるリンク（A→B→A→B→）や（１月→２月→３月→４月→）の開発になるという認識です。

Comment: @keitaro_so さん　なるほど！考え方が変わるんですね。ちょっと調べ方を変えてみます。ありがとうございます。